# How to create multiple variations of one XML structure using powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell

so my main goal is to be able to create multiple variations of an XML element (using powershell if possible). For example, the xml  structure below:

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>

</note>
```

**Question 1:** Is there a way to save that entire structure in one variable?

**Question 2:** How would I "save" that structure and create multiple copies of that structure with only one modification such as changing the Jani to cody and John?  I want to be able to make modified copies of that structure at will but don't know where to start.

Any help appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Here-String for that with placeholders.

```
$xmlTemplate = @"
<note>
    <to>{0}</to>
    <from>{1}</from>
    <heading>{2}</heading>
    <body>{3}</body>
</note>
"@
```

Then use that to create as many of these xml fragments as you like.
The placeholders `{0}`, `{1}` etc. get their true values using the `-f` Format operator like:

```
# this demo uses an array of Hashtables
$messages = @{To = 'Tove'  ; From = 'Jani'; Heading = 'Reminder'    ; Body = "Don't forget me this weekend!"},
            @{To = 'Bloggs'; From = 'Cody'; Heading = 'Cancellation'; Body = "No can do!"},
            @{To = 'Doe'   ; From = 'John'; Heading = 'Information' ; Body = "How about next weekend?"}

$messages.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    $xmlTemplate -f $_.To, $_.From, $_.Heading, $_.Body 
}
```

Result:

```
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
<note>
    <to>Bloggs</to>
    <from>Cody</from>
    <heading>Cancellation</heading>
    <body>No can do!</body>
</note>
<note>
    <to>Doe</to>
    <from>John</from>
    <heading>Information</heading>
    <body>How about next weekend?</body>
</note>
```

Comment: Neat! Quick (hopefully) question: what would be the simplest way to save all these fragments to one combined xml file?

Comment: @JackFleeting. Caprure the result as in `$result = $messages.GetEnumerator()`,  enclose that inside a root element and save as .xml

Comment: You're right, but I think you meant to address the comment to OP, not to me... I already upvoted the answer.

Comment: @JackFleeting Ah, sorry about that. I was too lazy to scroll up and check the OP's name.. Thanks for the upvote BTW ;)